# angularjs: trigger form validate programmatically (inside a controller)

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs

I have this situation in which I show 1 form in two steps. So to proceed to the second part of the form you have to click on a button. But before moving on I would like to perform form validation (all required fields need to be filled in). But because this is a normal button, the whole submit magic is not triggered and the validation does not happen. So the question I'm interested in is how can I trigger form validation in my controller ? It would even be better to trigger validation for specific fields. Just to give an idea, the form looks like

```
<form name="form" submit="save()">
    <section id="step1">
        <label for="username" required>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required />
        .....
        <button ng-click="proceed()">Proceed</button>        
    </section>
    <section id="step2">
         <label ...></label>
         <input...>
         ....
         <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

Also, I don't want to opt for disabling the button until all required fields are valid.

Comment: Why do you want 1 form? You can split it in two and use Angular's validation. And the "proceed" button should be enabled only if the first form is valid.

Comment: I think the right way is to done a directive for the validation ..

Comment: I choose one form because the whole submit back to the server (with file uploads etc) is easier, just one call. And how can this be done with a directive ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at the [ng-form directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angForm). It allows nesting forms (actually not HTML `<form>`s, but Angular NgFormControllers). So you can split your one form, used for posting to the server, into two logical forms, used for independent validation:

```
<form submit="save()">
    <div ng-form="form1">
        ...controls...
        <button ng-click="proceed()"
            ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Proceed</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-form="form2">
        ...controls...
        <button type="submit"
            ng-disabled="form2.$invalid || form1.$invalid">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can access the `$valid` property from your controller. Something like this could work.

```
 $scope.proceed = function(){     
      if($scope.form.username.$valid){
          //username is valid we may proceed to the next step
      }
 };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <button ng-click="proceed()">Proceed</button>
```

Replace To :

```
 <button ng-click="proceed()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Proceed</button>
```

Button will not visible button until all required fields are valid.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pSvSr/1/)

Comment: No, not correct. This isn't the same thing from a UI perspective. Disabling the button tends to confuse users. It's generally thought of as a better practice to always leave the button enabled, and only show error messages either while the form is being filled out or after form submission.